# Как вызвать javascript функцию из внешнего скрипта в onload?

Tags: javascript, html

`HTML`

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/externalScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="unique" onload="??? myFuncFromExternalJS()">qwerty</span>
</body>
```

`JavaScript`

```
function myFuncFromExternalJS() {
    alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот что пишут про это в интернете:

Событие onload используется как указатель, что веб-страница полностью загружена, включая содержание, изображения, стилевые файлы и внешние скрипты.

Применяется к тегам

```
<body>, <frameset>
```

В вашем случае:

```
<body onload='myFuncFromExternalJS();'>
```

Comment: это не работает. А если уже в другом скрипте есть такая же функция?

Comment: что конкретно не работает? не вызывается событие onload? или не вызывается ваша функция?

Comment: а как я проверю?

Comment: <body onload="alert('hello')"></body>

Comment: не работало, пробовал

Comment: прошу заметить, в вашем коде событие onload стоит не у тега body

Comment: ну так-то да, проверю сейчас

Comment: Работает всё хорошо

Comment: Отметьте, пожалуйста ответ как правильный =)

Comment: мой вопрос так и остался неотвеченным. Как же вызвать тогда не по `onload`, но функцию внешнего js

Comment: Тогда переформулируйте вопрос, потому что он про unload

Comment: Мне кажется это совсем другой вопрос

Answer (score -1):

Может быть

```
<body onload="myFuncFromExternalJS()">
```